# Material Design vs Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I just heard something like " Material design is already becoming a little bit out of fashion and how will it look like in 5 years" and "Lot of company stop using this and moving to Bootstrap".

Need some community feedback on this saying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing bootstrap vs material design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438336/choosing-bootstrap-vs-material-design)

Answer (score 0):

You can use material design and bootstrap separately or together, because they are not rival, each of them help complete the other. I think you look at the problem from the wrong angle.

- Material Design **provides the design** of graphic layouts for great UI/UX.
- Bootstrap are front-end frameworks to **create responsive pages from the design**. It can speed up your development by saving you from writing tons of code and that's it, nothing more!

Btw, material design is more than designs of web pages, it's using for mobile apps, posters,..